# Add ability to use wildcarded tags in search

Tags: bug, status-norepro, tags

It's possible to filter using a wildcard in a tag, for example [stargate*](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stargate*), and to use this in the favourite and ignored tags.

However, you can't do this in search.  Searching for `[stargate*]` gives the results for `[stargate]`.

If this could be used in search (and if it was also listed in the [search tips](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search)), perhaps more people would know that it can be done.

Comment: +1, I like this idea. Also, the tag suggestions will show you a few suggested tags with the characters you've imput already. But it's limited to like 6 or so.

Comment: [Passed this on to the devs. Not sure when that broke](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4362034#4362034)

Comment: @Gilles [I moved it on up](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/136923/155556)

Answer (score 3):

This is [supposedly implemented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1672/please-allow-wildcards-in-tag-searches/1726#1726) but looks broken.

You can enter the URL manually:

[https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stargate*](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stargate%2a)

but there doesn't seem to be a way to reach this URL from the search box, and I can't seem to combine with other search criteria (say, posts tagged `stargate*` and not tagged `stargate`).

Comment: Should I re-tag as [meta-tag:bug]?

Comment: @TonyMeyer I guess, yes. This is not in the search documentation, so maybe the post that says it exists is obsolete. I pinged the devs, let's see if they reply.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to have been fixed at some point since being posted.

I just put `[stargate*]` into the search box, and after submitting it the search terms were expanded to:

`[stargate] or [stargate-sg1] or [stargate-atlantis] or [stargate-universe] or [stargate-movie]`

Likewise, `[star-trek*]` becomes:

`[star-trek] or [star-trek-tng] or [star-trek-voyager] or [star-trek-ds9] or [star-trek-tos] or [star-trek-enterprise] or [star-trek-into-darkness] or [star-trek-2009] or [star-trek-data] or [star-trek-q] or [star-trek-tas] or [star-trek-the-doctor] or [star-trek-ph2] or [star-trek-judgment-rites] or [star-trek-iii] or [star-trek-countdown]`

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work, see for example [this link](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stargate*).

Comment: That's tag filtering, not search.  Tags always worked, and that link was included in the question.